# Open Graph - can I publish an action just to Ticker and Timeline (not to the News Feed)?

Tags: publish, facebook-opengraph, feed

I'm trying to post an action via open graph, but I prefer it doesn't show up in the newsfeed, but rather only the ticker and the timeline only.

Any way that can be achieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Found it - there's a "no_story" param that will just post to timeline aggregations but that will disable newsfeed posting. Unfortunately it'll also disable the Ticker post too.